# Button Toggling with JQuery & Bootstrap - How to change class of inactive after toggled

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap & Jquery.

How to change class of inactive after toggled

### Find my code below:

HTML Code

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
    <button class="btn btn-default">Active</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger active">Inacive</button>
```

---

SCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');  


        if ($(this).find('.btn-danger').size()>0) {
            $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-success');
            $(this).find('.btn').addClass('btn-default');
        }
        else if ($(this).find('.btn-success').size()>0) {
            $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-danger');
```

### }

addClass() seems not working..

Comment: It's working fine. http://jsbin.com/honaposuyo/edit?html,js,output Right click and inspect the Active button. Then click it. It will now have btn-success as a class.

Comment: I want to make btn-danger as btn-default once it is inactive..

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You don't have an inactive class. Do you mean once inactive is clicked? You need to describe the states you are looking for. What is the default state for each button (colors and such)? what is the state once active is clicked? What is the state when inactive is clicked? Currently you add class active to the opposite button anytime either button is clicked, but you don't have any CSS in your example so it does nothing. btn-danger remains on the inactive button always. Is that intended?

Comment: I've added some CSS to make the actions of the current code more clear http://jsbin.com/fayakenaki/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Hi MK, please check this code after inspect    

<td>
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
     <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default active btn-success" id="tglLampPass">Pass</button>

<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-success" id="tglLampNA">NA</button>
                                    
</div>

</td>

Active - class="btn btn-xs btn-default active btn-success"
Inactive - btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-success

I want to change Inactive as
btn btn-xs btn-default btn-success

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to disable and enable buttons on certain actions. Here is how I got it:

This is the button on my form:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Compute</button>
```

Add this line when you click on the button, in my case I am disabling the button once the form is submitted:

```
$('button', form).addClass('disabled').text("Computing...");
```

Enable back once you are done:

```
$('button', form).removeClass('disabled').text("Compute");
```

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: I dont have <form> in my file. i tried with $('#tglLampNA', document).addClass(btn-default');.. But still unable to get the result.. :(

Comment: can you paste your code? On what even are you trying to change the class, that part is missing in your code

Comment: Hi Pavitra, please check this code after inspect    

<td>
<div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
     <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default active btn-success" id="tglLampPass">Pass</button>

<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-success" id="tglLampNA">NA</button>
                                    
</div>

</td>

Active - class="btn btn-xs btn-default active btn-success"
Inactive - btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-success

I want to change Inactive as
btn btn-xs btn-default btn-success

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi!
Bootstrap toggle button typically acts like a checkbox. I see no issues in your html code. But where is your script? You have to write a script to toggle the class. Go through this link, it is detailed [link]http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/